# Restrict accesible files and directories on Apache MINA FtpServer

Tags: java, ftp, apache-mina, ftp-server

I've adopted Apache FtpServer as a library of my file sharing app. However I expose that I can set the permission of files/directories.

e.g. I have many files/directories under home directory, but I just want to make only the `~/A/`, `~/B/`, `~/c.txt` and `~/d.mp4` to be accessible via FTP connection.

Obviously it is not a good idea to make a temporary director as  client root and copy files into, but there seems to be no built-in solution of Apache FtpServer.

Currently I am considering about implementing a `FtpFile` class for myself, but I'm still confused and hesitating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own implementation of the `FileSystemFactory`.

Or derive your implementation from the default `NativeFileSystemFactory`. And change the `createFileSystemView` method to return only the entries you want.

Comment: That's what I need, thanks, I'm going to make a translate&re-translate of path in the FileSystemView. @Martin